# How to apply Regex pattern on a Dataframe's String columns in scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe yeadDF, created by reading an RDBMS table as below:

```
val yearDF = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", connectionUrl)
                                                .option("dbtable", s"(${query}) as year2017")
                                                .option("user", devUserName)
                                                .option("password", devPassword)
                                                .option("numPartitions",15)
                                                .load()
```

I have to apply a regex pattern to the above dataframe before ingesting it into Hive table on HDFS. Below is the regex pattern:

```
regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(%s, E'[\\\\n]+', ' ', 'g' ), E'[\\\\r]+', ' ', 'g' ), E'[\\\\t]+', ' ', 'g' ), E'[\\\\cA]+', ' ', 'g' ), E'[\\\\ca]+', ' ', 'g' )
```

I should be applying this regex only on the columns that are of datatype String in the dataframe: `yearDF`. I tried the following way:

```
val regExpr = yearDF.schema.fields
    .map(x => 
        if(x.dataType == String)
             "regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(%s, E'[\\\\n]+', ' ', 'g' ), E'[\\\\r]+', ' ', 'g' ), E'[\\\\t]+', ' ', 'g' ), E'[\\\\cA]+', ' ', 'g' ), E'[\\\\ca]+', ' ', 'g' ) as %s".format(x,x)
     )
yearDF.selectExpr(regExpr:_*)
```

But it gives me a compilation error: `Type mismatch, expected: Seq[String], actual: Array[Any]`

I cannot use `yearDF.columns.map` as this will act on all the columns and
I am unable to properly form the logic here.
Could anyone let me know how can I apply the regex mentioned above on the dataframe:`yearDF` only on the columns that are of String type ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `yearDF.selectExpr(regExpr:_*)` expects `regExpr` to be a Seq of String, while your regExpr is Array[Any]. Ok, that you see in the message. But why it's Array[Any]?

Look at your map function. for each field in schema, you are mapping:
 - each column with StringType to expression with regular expression
 - other cases -> None.

Btw., use `org.apache.spark.sql.types.StringType`, `String`.

So, instead, write:

```
val regExpr = yearDF.schema.fields
    .map(x => 
        if (x.dataType == StringType) 
              "regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(%s, E'[\\\\n]+', ' ', 'g' ), E'[\\\\r]+', ' ', 'g' ), E'[\\\\t]+', ' ', 'g' ), E'[\\\\cA]+', ' ', 'g' ), E'[\\\\ca]+', ' ', 'g' ) as %s".format(x.name, x.name)
        else x.name
     )
yearDF.selectExpr(regExpr:_*)
```

Comment: I am getting an exception:
extraneous input '(' expecting {')', ',', '.', '[', 'OR', 'AND', 'IN', NOT, 'BETWEEN', 'LIKE', RLIKE, 'IS', EQ, '<=>', '<>', '!=', '<', LTE, '>', GTE, '+', '-', '*', '/', '%', 'DIV', '&', '|', '^'}(line 1, pos 74)
regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(%s, E'[\\n]+', ' ', 'g' ), E'[\\r]+', ' ', 'g' ), E'[\\t]+', ' ', 'g' ), E'[\\cA]+', ' ', 'g' ), E'[\\ca]+', ' ', 'g' ) as
at com.partition.source.YearPartition$.main(YearPartition.scala:101)

I checked all the brackets and they are all balanced. Don't understand what is wrong.

Comment: @NewComer Ok, try with your string with s before " + format() ;) I maybe made some mistake in the string, but it's quite long to easily debug :P

Comment: @NewComer  Changed also in the answer

Comment: It says "Literals of type 'E' are currently not supported." when it is first encountered. I tried to look out for 'E' in regex_replace but couldn't find anything.

Comment: @NewComer you have it in here: `regexp_replace(%s, E'[\\\\n]+', ' ', 'g' )` and in other occurences ;) Probably a typo, but not related to the core of the question. Changing i.e. to `upper(%s) as %s` shows that code works, regexp may be wrong, but it's a candidate for other question

Answer (score 0):

I also faced similar issues while applying regex_replace() to only strings columns of a dataframe.
The trick is to make regEx pattern (in my case "pattern") that resolves inside the double quotes and also apply escape characters.

```
val pattern="\"\\\\\\\\[\\\\\\\\x{FFFD}\\\\\\\\x{0}\\\\\\\\x{1F}\\\\\\\\x{81}\\\\\\\\x{8D}\\\\\\\\x{8F}\\\\\\\\x{90}\\\\\\\\x{9D}\\\\\\\\x{A0}\\\\\\\\x{0380}\\\\\\\\]\""

val regExpr = parq_out_df_temp.schema.fields.map(x => 
if(x.dataType == StringType){s"regexp_replace(%s, $pattern,'') as %s".format(x.name,x.name)} 
else x.name)

val parq_out=parq_out_df_temp.selectExpr(regExpr:_*)
```

This worked fine for me!!